# Error in model.frame.default variable lengths differ with list of variable names

Tags: r, list, for-loop, aggregate

I am trying to use the aggregate function to show the average value of a score for specific subgroups. I have a lot of descriptive variables and I want to take combinations of two variables and find the average for each combine group. All variables are categorical, some have two entries, while others have multiple. I keep getting an error and while I have found some clues online, I am unsure of what to do.

```
variable_list <- c("gender","race","age", "disability", "job_level", "full_time_or_part_time", location", "office", "sex_orient")

for(i in 1:9){
  for(j in 1:9){
   holder <- aggregate(score ~ variable_list[i] + variable_list[j], survey, FUN=function(x) c(count=length(x), mean=mean(x) ))
   survey_combination <- bind_rows(survey_combination,holder)
  }
```

}

I want this code to produce a dataframe, but instead it gives me the error in the title.

Comment: You are missing a `"` before `location`.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to setup/initialize `survey_combination` before you start the for loops.  or do something like this:

```
firstTime = TRUE

variable_list <- c("gender","race","age", "disability", "job_level", "full_time_or_part_time", "location", "office", "sex_orient")

for(i in 1:9){
  for(j in 1:9){
    holder <- aggregate(score ~ variable_list[i] + variable_list[j], survey, FUN=function(x) c(count=length(x), mean=mean(x) ))

    if (firstTime) {
       survey_combination <- holder
       firstTime = FALSE
    } else {
       survey_combination <- bind_rows(survey_combination,holder)
    }

  }
}
```